A question about continuous functions with compact support in locally compact topological groups.
I'm having difficulties proving the following statement:

If $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff topological group and $C_c(G)$ is the space of continuous real functions on $G$ with compact support, then, given $\varepsilon > 0$ and a non-negative function $f\neq 0\in C_c(G)$, there exists a compact neighborhood $K$ of the identity such that $|f(xy)-f(yx)|<\varepsilon$ for every $x\in G$ and $y\in K$.

This statement is made in Lang's book "Real and Functional Analysis" (I'm reformulating the result here, which is based on a sentence from the book), in the proof of Theorem 2.3 in Chapter XII (for more context, this statement is at the end of page 316). Fixing $x\in G$ and using the continuity of the maps $g_x:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $h_x:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $g_x(y)=f(xy)$ and $h_x(y)=f(yx)$, I can show that there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of the identity such that $y\in U_x$ implies $|f(xy)-f(yx)|<\varepsilon$. I also know that every open neighborhood of the identity in $G$ contains a compact neighborhood of the identity. Therefore, there exists a compact neighborhood of the identity $K_x\subset U_x$ such that $y\in K_x$ implies $|f(xy)-f(yx)|<\varepsilon$. The problem here is that $K_x$ depends on $x$, and the original statement in the book claims that it's possible to obtain a compact neighborhood of the identity with this property valid for every $x\in G$.

If you take a symmetric $V_x$ such that $V_x V_x \subset U_x$, then a similar statement holds not only for $x$, but for every point in $x V_x$ (and $V_x$ in place of $U_x$). Get a finite cover for the support and take the intersection of those finite $V_x$.

Funny, I was reading this part of the book just a few days ago, and it took me hours until I figured it out. I wish some authors would bother to write a few more details.
Let $K$ be any compact set containing an open neighborhood $U$ of the identity. The function $T(x,y)=|f(xy)-f(yx)|$ is obviously continuous. For each $x\in G$ we have $T(x,e)=0$. Hence there are an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $V_x\subseteq U$ of $e$ such that $T(x',y')<\epsilon$ when $(x',y')\in U_x\times V_x$.
Now cover the compact set $A:=(\text{supp}f)K^{-1}\cup K^{-1}(\text{supp}f)$ by finitely many sets $U_{x_1},...,U_{x_n}$, and let $V=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}$. I claim that for all $(x,y)\in G\times V$ we have $T(x,y)<\epsilon$. Indeed, if $x\in A$ then $x\in U_{x_i}$ for some $i$, and since $y\in V_{x_i}$ we are done. And if $x\notin A$ then note that $f(xy)=f(yx)=0$ (remember, $V\subseteq U\subseteq K$), and so $T(x,y)=0<\epsilon$.
Now you can take any compact neighborhood of $e$ that is contained in $V$.
